# rust path module grand parent (several levels up)

Tags: rust, path

Is there a better way of getting an ancestor several levels up in the folder structure hierarchy using [std::path::Path](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#)?

At the moment if want to get the ancestor which is 5 levels up, I do the following (see below) but I feel there must be a better way.

I am aware of the method [ancestors](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.ancestors) but I couldn't see how to use it to improve this snippet.

```
use std::path::PathBuf;

let out_dir = PathBuf::from(env::var("OUT_DIR").unwrap());
let ancestor_dir = out_dir
    .parent()
    .unwrap()
    .parent()
    .unwrap()
    .parent()
    .unwrap()
    .parent()
    .unwrap()
    .parent()
    .unwrap();
```

Can this be written in a more readable way?

Comment: `out_dir.ancestors().take(5 + 1).last()` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`ancestors()` produces](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.ancestors) an iterator over `Path` and its ancestors. An iterator has a method called [`nth`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.nth) which you can use to return `nth` element of the iterator.

```
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    let out_dir = Path::new("/foo/bar/lev1/lev2/lev3/lev4");
    let ancestor_dir = out_dir.ancestors().nth(5).unwrap();
    println!("{}", ancestor_dir.display())
}
```